# deleted merge conflicts in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would rather not be writing this. but the pain is, that I didn't know what the conflict was or whatever and i found it in the gemfile.lock and DELETED IT! and I read someone said not to do that..so i don't know how to fix my problem. Here is my gemfile, and gemfile.lock.

-------->Gemfile<----------

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



ruby '2.2.6'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre5'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
   gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**---------> Gemfile ends here <--------**

```
        GIT
       remote: https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git
  revision: eea3aa21f3867dc182e4db24d1c765bdbcb3df34
  specs:
    inherited_resources (1.7.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
      responders

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.2)
      nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.2)
      actionview (= 5.0.2)
      activejob (= 5.0.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.2)
      actionview (= 5.0.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre5)
      arbre (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.6)
      jquery-rails
```

**-------->GEMFILE.LOCK ENDS HERE<------------**

Comment: what exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the Gemfile.lock and run following command ie

```
bundle install
```

It will again create the Gemfile.lock and added dependency gems.

Comment: thanks very much. found another way to do it is run 'git reset --hard'

Comment: Try git checkout Gemfile.lock

Comment: git checkout Gemfile Gemfile.lock

Comment: am getting new error: error parsing 'Gemfile' syntax error unexpected...

Comment: Check your Gemfile code, is it correct? Try bundle install